# How to connect android app to LAMP server

Tags: php, android, apache, server, lamp

I have created a php server script to be executed with LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL Php)

```
<?php
    // set some variables
    $host = "127.0.1.1";
    $port = 3651;

    // don't timeout!
    set_time_limit(0);

    // create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

    // bind socket to port
    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");

    while(true) {
        // start listening for connections
        $result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
        echo "after listen\n";
        // accept incoming connections
        // spawn another socket to handle communication

        $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
        echo "after accept\n";
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if ($pid == -1) {
            die('could not fork');
        } else if ($pid) {
            // we are the parent
        } else {
            // we are the child
            // Use $spawn for communication as you see fit
            // exit();
            // read client input
            $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
            var_dump($input);
            // clean up input string
            //$input = trim($input);
            var_dump(json_decode($input));

            // reverse client input and send back
            $output = strrev($input) . "\n";
            socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
            socket_close($spawn);
        }  
    }
    socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I executed it on terminal using command `php test_server.php`
I checked my private ip using ifconfig as `192.168.0.105`
I cannot setup a connection with this file from my android mobile app whose code is as

```
private String HttpPost(String myUrl) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        Log.e("HTTPpost","url Object created");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.e("HTTPpost","connection opened");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        setPostRequestContent(conn, objectToBeSent);
        conn.connect();
        Log.e("HTTPpost","connected");
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("HTTPpost",line);
            result.append(line);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    private void setPostRequestContent(HttpURLConnection conn,
                                       JSONObject jsonObject) throws IOException {
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
        Log.i(context.toString(), jsonObject.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
    }
```

where I passed 'myurl' to 'HttpPost' function as `http://192.168.0.105/test_server.php:3651`
My server output remains `after listen` and have not shown any sign of socket acceptance
Android apps debugging logs are

```
2020-08-11 22:45:18.833 17839-17978/com.example.testapplication E/HTTPpost: url Object created
2020-08-11 22:45:18.850 17839-17978/com.example.testapplication E/HTTPpost: connection opened
```

I have set the network permissions as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I have also verified that both my mobile and laptop are connected to the same wifi.

Phease help and provide some idea about how to proceed.

Comment: `$host = "127.0.1.1";` Why do you bind to localhost? Nobody can reach you now.

Comment: Are you on Android Q?

Comment: Can a browser on your pc reach your server? If so which ip did you use?

Comment: Can a browser on your Android device reach your server? –

Comment: yes i am using android 10. Yes the server can be reached by both browser on pc as well as browser on my android phone. i used the ip address of my pc.

Comment: On using debug statements in Android code, I found that problem comes when android app tries to get an OutputStream for the connection. That is the problem comes at the first statement of setPostRequestContent function.

Comment: On Android 10 you cannot use the http protocol any more. Google wants you to use https. To continue using http add usesClearTextTraffic true to manifest.

Comment: Thanks, Adding usesClearTextTraffic=true helped a little, now Connection is able to get OutputStream and conn.connect() also gets executed but it still fails at getting the inputStream. Also the server has not accepted the socket connection yet.

Comment: If the server did not accept the connection then of course the client is not connected and cannot get an input or output stream.

Comment: `where I passed 'myurl' to 'HttpPost' function as http://192.168.0.105/test_server.php:3651` That is a strange url. Never seen before. Please tell how that should work.

Comment: `Yes the server can be reached by both browser on pc as well as browser on my android phone.` ?? You mean that they can connect with your php script. But how would a browser start a client on port 3651 that connects with your php socket? What kind of data would it send? Please explain why you said that browsers can connect.

Comment: how should be the format of the url... 192.168.0.105 is my PC's ip.

Comment: I can execute my php script server from browser by writing
http://192.168.0.105/test_server.php........ but im  not able to do this with android app

Answer (score 0):

The client using port 80 connects with the apache server and your php script is started. The php script is doing nothing with the posted data and is echoing nothing .

So it does not communicate with the client.

The only thing it does is starting a server listening on port 3651. But it only listens as there will never be a client trying to connect to that port.

Your HttpUrlConnection will not do that as it uses port 80.

Impossible setup.

Comment: What changes do i make in the code now? Please suggest.

Comment: As you did not tell what you want to do with your construction i have no idea.

Comment: You could write another app that tries to connect with your php socket server. What your code does now is just starting a php socket server. But it does not try to connect with that socket server.

Comment: With this construction I am trying to send a json object  "objectToBeSent" from android app to the php script and to get some reply from php to the android app back

Comment: Then write a completely different php script as you do not need a socket server there.

Comment: What should i use in my php script instead of using socket? Please suggest. Thanks